# Reattached Designer.cs to mainform.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

So when I grabbed some files of a different solution, and pasted them into a different solution, someone my Mainform and designer got detached. If I run my program the form shows correctly, but when i view my form in design mode, its a blank form. Anyone know how to reattach the designer?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the solution explorer, move the designer file under the MainForm

Comment: Doesnt work, Cannot move because source folder is the same as the destination folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the .csproj file with a text editor (Notepad is fine) to add the missing `<DependentUpon>` element.  So it looks like this:

```
<Compile Include="Yadayada.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Yadayada.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Yadayada.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: Well i converted from a vb project... and i have no csproj, is there anyway i can generate one?

Comment: WTF???  Select the project in the Solution Explorer window and look at the "Project Folder" property as displayed in the Properties window.

Comment: Opps looks like the csproj file was just burried under other files. I couldnt find it earlier, but found it now. Thanks +1

Comment: I spent some time applying this same method to fix a project that got messed up for unknown reasons. Everything looked great and I was coding/building happily for the rest of the day. Then when I came back this morning and reopened the solution in VS, it was all back to the way it was before! I'm not sure if there's a bigger problem or if that was a fluke and it should stick next time.